# Delete duplicated records from two databases

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I manage to identify duplicate records from two different databases:

```
select * from 
    taskperformance a,  taskperformance@dm_prod b
where 
    a.activityin = b.activityin
    and a.completiondate = b.completiondate
```

How can I delete duplicated records from `b`?

I tried:

```
delete taskperformance@dm_prod  where exist ( 
select * from 
    taskperformance a,  taskperformance@dm_prod b
where 
    a.activityin = b.activityin
    and a.completiondate = b.completiondate )
```

But it deletes more than what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't re-reference `b` in the subquery:

```
delete taskperformance@dm_prod b
where exists (
    select * from taskperformance a
    where a.activityin = b.activityin 
    and a.completiondate = b.completiondate 
)
```

Comment: Oops I'm sorry. Bad editing. I didn't re-reference b. It is a typo. 

I dod it like you posted and it delete all the records. .. :(  Thank god I put autocommit to false... ( didn't I? :-o )

Comment: @Greg Ogle:  Could you expand that comment a bit. Suppose I don't know what your are talking about ;)

Comment: He's mentioning that I removed the alias of 'b' - that's probably a MSSQL v Oracle thing... but I'm not talking about the alias in my answer, I'm talking about the fact that you mention the table again in the FROM clause of the subquery. In my answer, I only mention taskperformance in the FROM clause of the subquery, not taskperformance@dm_prod

Comment: It says the db link does not exists: ( like the field was part of the db link name ) : Error: ORA-04054: database link DM_PROD.COMPLETIONDATE does not exist

Comment: Ah, yup. Cool. In SQL Server you can't use an alias in quite that way, so I'm always in the habit of using the tablename if I use this construct. Great that you got it sorted. :)